# Krusader quick search on Ubuntu 20.04 : What syntax to use to search for filenames with RegEx?

Tags: regex, krusader

Installed Krusader on Ubuntu 20.04 as Nautilus dropped sorting of search results.
Cant find a way (syntax) to do a QuickSearch with RegEx; I know how to write RegEx syntax, but what special character(s) let Krusader know in QuickSearch, that the search string is a RegEx?

Answer (score 1):

I think [the documentation](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/krusader/krusader/basic-functions.html#quicksearch) is incorrect about Quick Search and it doesn't support regular expressions. But the text in the following section about Quick Filter is interesting:

> You can use wildcards for the filtering. e.g. use "a*b" to filter files which have "a" and "b" in their names.

Based on some simple testing, it seems wildcards work in Quick Search too (e.g., `.g*[0-9]` opened `.gimp-2.8`, but `.g.*[0-9]` didn't). Or you can use the full general search.

Comment: Ok, what of it?

Comment: Hi muru,
thanks, I've read the docs before submitting my question and also use wildcards with rather less efficient results.
As the Krusader version update details explicitly mention the new Regex functionality (and I'm really into Regex) I'll probably address the issue to the SW publishers (and update this question issue if I there are any sense making news)